# Finding the inverse polynomial in $\frac{\mathbb{k}[x]}{(g)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

$f(x) = x^6 + x^5 + 1$, $g(x) = x+2$, $f(x) = g(x)(x^5 - x^4 + 2x^3 - 4x^2 + 8x -16) + 33$

So, after this I should find the inverse polynomial $f^{-1}(x)$ for $f(x)$ in $\frac{\mathbb{k}[x]}{(g)}$, where $\mathbb{k} = \mathbb{Q}$.

How I am understand it: for $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ should exist a inverse polynomial $f^{-1}(x)$ like that: $f(x)f^{-1}(x) = 1$, where $1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ -- multiplicative unit. In $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(g)}$ inverse for $f(x)$ should looking like that (as I thought): $[f(x)]*[f^{-1}(x)] = [g(x)]$, i.e. I should find the class of polynomials, any element of which should "cancel" the remainder $33$ of division $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. But how we can make $0$ from $33$ just by multiplying it on another polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to make $0$ from $33$, you want to make $1$. So what about $\frac 1{33}$ as the inverse?

This quotient field is secretly $\mathbb Q$, with $x=-2$. We're simply setting $x+2=0$. So your inverse can just be a number in all cases.

Comment: But we will have non-zero remainder, no? 

$f(x) * \frac{1}{33} = (x^5 - x^4 + 2x^3 - 4x^2 + 8x - 16)(x+2)* \frac{1}{33} + 1$, no?

Comment: @Just Correct. But in the quotient anything multiplied by $x+2$ becomes $0$, so that term disappears and you're left with $1$.

Comment: I am not really understand this momet in theory: why in $\frac{\mathbb{k}[x]}{(g)}$, if unit-element is class $ [g(x)] $ we can have in this class elements with non-zero remainder.. 

As I thought before, any element of the class $[g(x)]$ should be representing like this: $f(x) = \alpha * g(x) + 0$, no? where $\alpha \in \mathbb{k}[x]$

Comment: @Just The unit element is $[g(x)] +1$. $[g(x)] $ is the zero element.